# Button gets the default position every time app is started or moving to any other activity

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I have created an image button programmatically and I am using ontouchlistener to drag and drop the button anywhere on the screen by setting layout parameters. This is working fine.

I want that the button would be at the same position where I dropped it, every time I start the app or if I move to any other activity.

Comment: that is because you are not saving the latest state of button. Store the final coordinates somewhere in Sharedpreferences or Database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you start the activity read the button position from shared preference and set the button position to particular location x,y and when you are dragging and dropping save this x,y location to your SharedPreference that will work.

Comment: you can upvote and accept the answer, however @Shahzeb made a comment so I can upvote his comment.

Comment: Sorry I do not have much reputation to upvote an answer.